# Pass parameters from component to component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, native, router

I'm making an aplication using router flux. Everything works fine until I encountered this problem. I don't know how can i pass a function with some parameters from the a form, to the toolbar (where the user should press the send button). Here is the where the router is defined:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
          <Scene key="SplashPage" component={SplashPage} initial={true} panHandlers={null}/>
          <Scene key="drawer" component={NavigationView} open={false} direction="vertical">
            <Scene key="main" hideNavBar={false}>
              <Scene key="MainPage" component={MainPage} search="" title={I18n.t("nautal")} mainIcon="menu" secondaryIcon={["search"]} mainAction={()=>Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', open: value => !value })} secondaryAction={()=>Actions.SearchBoatsPage()} navBar={MyToolbar} panHandlers={null}/>
              <Scene key="CheckListPage" component={CheckListPage} title={I18n.t("checklist")} navBar={MyToolbarEmpty} panHandlers={null}/>
              <Scene key="MeteoPage" component={MeteoPage} title={I18n.t("meteo")}  mainIcon="menu" secondaryIcon={["search","done"]} navBarSearch={true} mainAction={()=>Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', open: value => !value })} navBar={MyToolbar} panHandlers={null}/>
              <Scene key="InfoPortsPage" component={InfoPortsPage} title={I18n.t("infoPorts")} navBar={MyToolbar} mainIcon="menu" secondaryIcon={["search","done"]} mainAction={()=>Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', open: value => !value })} navBarSearch={true} panHandlers={null}/>
              <Scene key="ToolsPage" component={ToolsPage} title={I18n.t("tools")} navBar={MyToolbarEmpty} panHandlers={null}/>
              <Scene key="SearchBoatsPage" component={SearchBoatsPage} title={I18n.t("searchBoats")} mainIcon="arrow-back" secondaryIcon={["done"]} mainAction={()=>Actions.pop()} secondaryAction={()=>Actions.MainPage()} navBar={MyToolbar} panHandlers={null}/>
              <Scene key="CompassPage" component={CompassPage} title={I18n.t("compass")} navBar={MyToolbarEmpty} panHandlers={null}/>
              <Scene key="MOBPage" component={MOBPage} title={I18n.t("manOverboard")} navBar={MyToolbarEmpty} panHandlers={null}/>
            </Scene>
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the toolbar component (with the send button):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import {Toolbar} from 'react-native-material-design';
import I18n from '../core/Translations';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { Kohana } from 'react-native-textinput-effects';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

class MyToolbar extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    tabBarSearch: false,
    counter: false,
    secondIcon: this.props.secondaryIcon[0]
  };
  this.pressButton = this.pressButton.bind(this); 
 } 

 pressButton() { 
  if(typeof this.props.secondaryAction!="undefined"){
   this.props.secondaryAction();
  }

  if(this.props.navBarSearch){
   var icon = (!this.state.counter) ? this.props.secondaryIcon[1] : this.props.secondaryIcon[0];
   this.setState({
    tabBarSearch: !this.state.tabBarSearch,
    secondIcon: icon,
    counter: !this.state.counter
   }); 
  }
 } 

 render() {
  return (
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', right: 0, left: 0}}>
    <Toolbar
     title={(this.state.tabBarSearch) ? null : this.props.title}
     icon={this.props.mainIcon}
     onIconPress= {this.props.mainAction}
     actions={[{
      icon: this.state.secondIcon,
      onPress: this.pressButton
     }]}

     overrides={{backgroundColor: '#015B83'}}

     rightIconStyle={{
      margin: 10
     }}
    >
     <Kohana
      style={{ backgroundColor: '#015B83' }}
      iconClass={Icon}
      iconName={'search'}
      iconColor={'white'}
      labelStyle={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20}}
      inputStyle={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontWeigth:'bold' }}
      autoFocus={true}
      placeholder={'Search'}
      placeholderTextColor ={'#aaa'}
     />
    </Toolbar>
   </View>
  )
 }
}

module.exports = MyToolbar;
```

and here is the form( where the user imputs data to send):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StatusBar, Dimensions, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import DrawerLayout from 'react-native-drawer-layout';
import TextField from 'react-native-md-textinput';
import {Button } from 'react-native-material-design';
import NavigationView from '../Components/NavigationView';
import MyToolbarEmpty from '../Components/MyToolbarEmpty';
import MyToolbar from '../Components/MyToolbar';
import I18n from '../core/Translations';
import STYLES from '../core/Styles';
import GLOBAL  from '../core/Global';

var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class SearchBoatsPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      country:'',
      area:'',
      duration:'',
      startDate:''
    };
    this.searchData = this.searchData.bind(this); 
  }

  searchData(){ 
    var search = {country:this.state.country, area:this.state.area, duration:this.state.duration, startDate:this.state.startDate};
    Actions.MainPage({search: search});
  } 

  render() {
    const goToPageTwo = () => Actions.CheckListPage({text: 'Hello World!'}); 
    const openDrawer = () => Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', open: value => !value });
    return (
     <View>
     <StatusBar
      hidden={false}
      backgroundColor='#096f9c'
     /> 
        <ScrollView>
       <View style={STYLES.container}>        
            <View style={STYLES.subContainer}>
              <TextField onChangeText={country => this.setState({country})} label={ I18n.t("country") } highlightColor={'#08AE9E'} value={this.state.country}/>
              <TextField onChangeText={area => this.setState({area})} label={ I18n.t("area") } highlightColor={'#08AE9E'} value={this.state.area}/>
              <TextField onChangeText={duration => this.setState({duration})} label={ I18n.t("duration") } highlightColor={'#08AE9E'} value={this.state.duration}/>
              <TextField onChangeText={startDate => this.setState({startDate})} label={ I18n.t("startDate") } highlightColor={'#08AE9E'} value={this.state.startDate}/>
            </View>
            <View style={STYLES.bottomButton}>
              <Button 
                onPress={this.searchData}
                text={ I18n.t("search") }
                theme = 'dark'
                textColor  = 'white'
                raised={true} 
                overrides={{backgroundColor: '#08AE9E', rippleColor:'#39beb1'}}
              />
            </View>
       </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
    )
  }

  _setDrawer() {
    this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer();
  } 
}
```

To summarise, i want to send parameters from the form to the toolbar, so i will be able to send the form info by pressing the button on the toolbar.